# Impedir recarregar a pagina caso exista algo dentro da div

Tags: javascript

Como eu poderia impedir o recarregamento caso existisse algo dentro de uma `div`? e seria possível impedir fazendo uma outra `div` aparecer com o pedido de confirmação aviso invés do `alert` do javascript? estou sem ideias de como poderia fazer isso.

Comment: Não é possível impedir o recarregamento de uma página. O que você pode fazer é utilizar `localStorage` para salvar determinado conteúdo e então capturar-los quando a página for carregada.

Comment: Impedir o carregamento não pode porque o JS só vai saber que o elemento existe quando ele for carregado.

Comment: não teria como nem executar uma ultima função antes de ser carregada a próxima pagina?

Comment: Utilize o evento `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: Deu certo, vlw.

Comment: Agora que entendi rs... eu entendi "carregar" em vez de "REcarregar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara quanto a recarregamento acho meio difícil bloquear isso, o máximo que você consegue bloquear seria a tecla f5 mas quanto checar o conteudo da DIV eu posso te ajudar.

Você pode utilizar o jQuery com o seguinte código.

```
 if ($('div').html() !== ""){
    alert('Esta div possui conteudo');
    }
    else{
    alert('sta div possui conteudo');
    }
```